# How can WHERE constraints be passed to a count(...) function in an inner SELECT query in a VIEW?

Tags: sqlite, sql-view

I have a VIEW in SQLite which is, schematically, like this:

```
SELECT ownerid, field, origin, count FROM (
    SELECT 
        null AS ownerid,
        table1.somefield AS field,
        0 AS origin,
        count(table2.ownerid) AS count
    FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        table2.ownerid AS ownerid,
        table2.someotherfield AS field,
        1 AS origin,
        1 AS count
)
```

I'm calling this with a `SELECT FROM viewname WHERE ownerid=? OR origin=0` type query—in other words, what I want is entries from the first table, plus entries from the second table where the owner id is correct.

The count column for the first table is supposed to be the count of all rows in the second table that match the constraint—in other words, whose ownerid is the one selected for.  What I currently get is the count for the entire table.

How can I constrain the expression inside the `count(...)` function call to match the query constraint being passed to the VIEW?

Answer (score 0):

```
count(SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE ownerid=?)
```

what I think you really need though is to simplify your view and restrict the information after like so.

```
SELECT ownerid, field, origin, count FROM (
    SELECT 
        null AS ownerid,
        table1.somefield AS field,
        0 AS origin
    FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        table2.ownerid AS ownerid,
        table2.someotherfield AS field,
        1 AS origin
)
```

and then get the required counts and such from it like this

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN viewname.ownerid IS NULL THEN COUNT(select * from table2 where ownerid=?) ELSE 1 END
FROM viewname
```

Comment: How do I get the `?` inside the VIEW as a variable, so to speak?  More generally, how do I impose constraints on the count from outside the VIEW?

Comment: http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Parameters-are-not-allowed-in-views-td50403.html

Comment: Well, that scuppers that.  Thanks, though.